# Migrating from Hosted-Exchange to Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, hosted-exchange

I am moving the mail for our company from a Hosted Exchange back into a self hosted Exchange box running Exchange 2010.  I have seen articles on using PST files to migrate the mail, but there seem to be some issues when doing that (unable to reply to migrated mail, unable to move contacts).  Is there a better way?  Is my only option to manually create the accounts in the new domain and import PST files?

Edit:  The hosted exchange is Exchange 2007 through Mailstreet.  I haven't contacted them yet as I wanted to have a plan in place before I did.  I am not sure what type of access I can get to the servers.

Comment: What version of exchange is the hosted and what sort of access do you have to it?

Comment: Updated with Exchange 2007 and unknown level of access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a USENIX member you can read the following PDF: [Migrating from Hosted Exchange Service to In-House Exchange Solution](http://www.usenix.org/publications/login/2010-10/pdfs/mckee.pdf). If you are not a USENIX member, the article will be unlocked in a month or so IIRC.

Comment: Not a member at this point.

Comment: The article covered the gotchas and solutions quite well.  Thank you for the pointer to the article!